# Running a compainion application at install

Tags: setup-project, visual-studio-2015

I have two WPF applications in the same solution. One is a configuration helper for the other and needs to be run before the 'big' app is run. In the VS Setup project I have included the Primary Output from both applications.

I want to run the configuration helper during the Commit phase of setup so I added a Custom Action consisting of the Primary Output of configuration helper and marked the Installer Class as false.

When I run the resulting msi, both applications are installed in the same folder as desired, but I then get an error that 'a program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected.' The msi then uninstalls.

I was hoping the configuration helper would be kicked off as the msi exits, but would also be happy with the installer hanging open until the configuration helper exits.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program you ran as a custom action has failed, probably crashed. It may need some extra error checking or tracing to see what's going on. Programs that run as custom actions are not in the same environment as running them from the interactive user's desktop. The working directory is probably not what you expect (so file paths must be specified in full) and it's probably running with the system account, because that's the way Everyone installs work, so any assumptions about user locations (including the interactive user's desktop, user folders, access to the network, access to databases, ability to show forms) will be wrong and are likely to be failure points. It's better to run configuration tools like this when the app first starts because you are now running in a normal user environment.